# If $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a prime and $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$, show that the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p)$ has order $p^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers, euclidean-domain

**The Problem**: Let $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a prime with $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$. Show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p)$ has order $p^2$.

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra $\mathit{3^{rd}}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote.

**My Attempt**: Indeed, $p=a^2+b^2$ for some $a, b\in\mathbb{Z}$, and we have that $N(p)=p^2$. I tried to establish an equivalence relation using the Euclidean Algorithm $\alpha=\beta p+\gamma$ with $N(\gamma)<N(p)=p^2$ for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, to no avail. Any **HINT** would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The quotient group $\Bbb{Z}^2/p\Bbb{Z}^2$ has $p^2$ elements for any non-zero integer, no need that it is prime or $\equiv 1\bmod 4$.

Comment: @reuns I have never seen that quotient before hence I am afraid that it is not something I'm allowed to use...

Comment: The assumption $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ prime is irrelevant. Only need that $p$ is a non-zero integer. What is the quotient ring (also a quotient group..) $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(p)$ to you? For example with $p=2$ can you write down its elements?

Comment: @reuns Thank you!